# No data toast in android while search results do not match

Tags: android, android-filterable

I have implemented filterable. 
I have checked filter results on `onPublished` i.e if(`filterResults.count==0`) and toast over there but it shows the toast every time `searchtext` matches or not, See below for the reference,

Here is my code on adapter:

```
@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {
            String charString = charSequence.toString();
            Log.d("cndbdhdh",charString);

            if (charString.isEmpty()) {

                recentUserArrayListArrayListTemp = recentUserArrayListArrayList;
            } else {

                ArrayList<MostRecentUsers.RecentUserList> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();


                for (MostRecentUsers.RecentUserList androidVersion : recentUserArrayListArrayList) {

                    if (androidVersion.getName().toLowerCase().contains(charString) || androidVersion.getPhone().toLowerCase().contains(charString) ) {

                        filteredList.add(androidVersion);
                    }


                }

                recentUserArrayListArrayListTemp = filteredList;
            }

            FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
            filterResults.values = recentUserArrayListArrayListTemp;
            return filterResults;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {



            notifyDataSetChanged();
            if (filterResults.count==0){
                Toast.makeText(activity, "no data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            }else { 
                recentUserArrayListArrayListTemp = (ArrayList<MostRecentUsers.RecentUserList>) filterResults.values;

            }



        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should also do

```
  filterResults.count = recentUserArrayListArrayListTemp.size();
```

in your `performFiltering`

Comment: I will ask you other issue in this comment okay. Will you help me?

Comment: @Elisha OK go ahead :)

Comment: if (id == R.id.change_language) {
                if (language.equals("ne")) {
                    setLocale("en");
                    recreate();
                } else {
                    setLocale("ne");
                    recreate();
                }
            }
In above code, the code is inside onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) on Navigation activity. The only  problem is, if I recreate NavDrawer goes closed and if I donot recreate, donot refresh the language selection.
Now I want to change language from NavDrawer and drawer should remain open.Help me please.

Comment: @Elisha Can you ask this in a separate question so that I can ask you some more details to answer it? 
comment the question link when you are done :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182352/discussion-between-elisha-and-marzieh-heidari).

Comment: https://hackmd.io/p42ZjCtZSrm6Y4U5EJHQAA 
Please look here, I have described and paste code here.

Comment: mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT); write this code after recreate() method.